# Ionic Pro App fails to build on Ionic's build service due to an issue with a package

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, jsonpath

I am using the [jsonpath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath) package from NPM on my Ionic 3.0 app. It is in my package.json like so:

```
> "jsonpath": "1.0.0",
```

On my local machine, the app builds successfully and all is well.

However, once I push the code off to Ionic's servers, the code fails to transpile because of the following error:

> Cannot find module 'JSONPath'

I noticed that earlier in the build log npminstall appears to successfully install this dependency:

> jsonpath@1.0.0 postinstall /usr/src/app/node_modules/jsonpath
>
> ...
>
> npm install succeeded

So unfortunately there is little clue what the problem might be.

Here's how I am referencing this dependency in my TypeScript:

```
import { JsonPath } from 'JSONPath';
```

Am I doing something silly anywhere? Any suspicions as to why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by simply changing how I reference the package from this:

```
import { JsonPath } from 'JSONPATH';
```

to

```
import { JsonPath } from 'jsonpath';
```

It unfortunately didn't cross my mind that it would be case-sensitive. Also, why would it work on my local machine but not using Ionic's build tools? What's different? Is the Ionic build service *stricter*?